# How to return a map function that has hyphenated field in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, meteor

I was working with Meteor and mongoDB and I've run into a problem. My schema has a hyphenated name and I'm unable to retrieve it's value from `map`. How do I circumvent this?

My mongoDB collection has a field named:

```
"loopback-mode" : "no-loopback",
```

My query being:

```
db.collection.find({templateName:"someTemplate"},{"loopback-mode":1,_id:0}).map(function(c) {return c.loopback-mode;})[0];
```

`c.loopback-mode` seems to be causing the of problem.

I get the error saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token -
```

I've tried `c[loopback-mode], c["loopback-mode"], c."loopback-mode"` etc,
but to no success. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to go should be

```
....map(function(c) { return c['loopback-mode']; })...
```

I just tested it - see the GIF below

[image: Test]

As you mentioned that you tested that already, please try again and if it still does not work then please share the error (if any). The initial syntax error should be gone for sure.

Comment: Thanks! It actually worked for me too. I guess I had a typo somewhere and bungled it up.